# What is this Wix statement doing?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I cannot find an explanation in the Wix help or online as to what this code does:

```
<Binary Id="WixUI_Bmp_Dialog" SourceFile="!(wix.WixUIDialogBmp=$(var.dialogBmp))" />
```

Specifically, the evaluated value of the SourceFile attribute?

I can see that wix.WixUIDialogBmp dereferences a WixVariable of that name.

I can see that $(var.dialogBmp) dereferences a defined preprocessor variable.

But I do not understand the assignment of one to the other, or the "!()" notation.

As I understand the way that this code functions, it could perhaps be a null coalescing expression, because the WixVariable is not necessarily defined in the code, while the other variable is a constant and always defined. But I can find nothing on a null coalescing expression in Wix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!(wix.variable)` is how you refer to a bind-time variable. The `=` "clause" provides a default value for the bind-time variable. That lets the WiX build supply a default bitmap but lets you override it by providing a path in the `WixUIDialogBmp` bind-time variable.